# Can I exclude source files from google app engine deploy in Java

Tags: google-app-engine

In my current google apps project I have set up two source folders, src for production code and test for junit tests and the like. Is there some way to specify that only the src folder is deployed, while the test folder is still available for local testing?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Including_and_Excluding_Files That wasn't too hard to Google, really.

Answer (score 6):

From the `<resource-files>` row in the [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref?csw=1#syntax) table:

> `<exclude>`
>
> Files and directories matching  patterns will not be uploaded
>   or available to your application code. However, these files and
>   directories will still be accessible to your application when running
>   on the local Development Server. For more information, see [Including
>   and excluding files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref?csw=1#include_exclude).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <resource-files>
>   <include path="/**.xml" />
>   <exclude path="/feeds/**.xml" />
> </resource-files>
> ```
>
> This example demonstrates how to designate all .xml files as resource
>   files except those in the feeds/ directory and all of its
>   subdirectories.

Comment: While I appreciate the attempt, this was not for a file that is in the war directory. This is actually a question for source code filtering so java unit tests are not placed on the server. So far, by my experimenting it looks like the root directory that appengine-web.xml starts at is war while my code is above that level.

Comment: Only files in the war directory are uploaded.  If you're using eclipse, the compiler is probably putting your output JARs into the war directory.  Just remove the test JARs from there before you deploy.