# How do I select which files to deploy to a Standard Environment AppEngine in Google Cloud?

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-go

How do I limit the files deployed to the AppEngine instances?

I am updating a Google AppEngine Standard Environment deployment from 1.11 to the 1.12+ environment. To be able to compile, I need to create a go.mod in the top-level directory of the project. The project builds and deploys just fine.

Previously, only the files relative to the directory the `gcloud app deploy` command was run is was available in the container, so my versions were around 20 megabyte (binary, some static HTML files, and apparently the main package go source, for some reason). The rest of the source files (vendored code and handler implementation) is in a directory parallel to the main.go:

```
$GOPATH
├── web       << "gcloud app deploy" runs from here
│   ├── main.go
│   ├── .gcloudignore
│   └── html
│       └── index.html
├── handler
│   └── implementation
├── cloud.google.com
│   ├── datastore
:   :
```

Now, all files from the go.mod and down are deployed, including all packages and all the vendored third-party source code, resulting in a 250 megabyte deployed image.

```
src        << "gcloud app deploy" runs from here
├── go.mod
├── .gcloudignore
├── web
│   ├── main.go
│   └── html
│       └── index.html
├── handler
│   └── implementation
├── vendor 
│   └── cloud.google.com
│       ├── datastore
:       :
```

I am trying to find any documentation on how to limit which files get deployed to the versioned instance, but fall short. The `.gcloudignore` file drops some files from the upload, but if I add the sources here the project, quite obviously, cannot build. I cannot find anything in the [app.yaml reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=go) on how to limit the list of deployed files (I was under the impression it would only include the files listed as `upload` clauses, but that is quite apparently incorrect).

My .gcloudignore file is the standard one generated by gcloud, with a few minor additions (comment lines stripped for brevity):

```
.gcloudignore
.git
.gitignore
.gitrepo
*.exe
*.exe~
*.dll
*.so
*.dylib
*.test
*.out
Makefile
web
*.sh
```

Here is a snippet from app.yaml:

```
runtime: go119
app_engine_apis: true
default_expiration: "1d"
env_variables:
  GCE_METADATA_HOST: "169.254.169.254"

handlers:
- url: /
  login: required
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: html/favicon.ico
  upload: html/favicon.ico

- url: /api/?.*
  script: auto
  secure: always

- url: /ping/?.*
  script: auto
  secure: always

- url: /offline.js
  login: optional
  static_files: html/offline.js
  upload: html/offline.js
  secure: always

- url: /_ah/queue/go/delay
  script: auto
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

Comment: Just to confirm - you're saying that when you added some of those files to your ```.gcloudignore``` and deployed your App, either the deploy failed because it couldn't correctly build the App or it went through but your App didn't work because it couldn't be started properly (cos some dependencies were missing)?

Comment: Yes, the files are used to build the Go application in the cloud. In GOPATH mode it sends all the files in my main app directory, which is parallel to the vendored source. In go.mod mode it includes all the files from the go.mod directory, which is above the vendored source. I'll add that to the question text.

Comment: Did you refer to this [migration guide](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/go-differences). Also, please share your .gcloudignore file for its syntax/correctness for the new modified directory structure.

Comment: Yes, I have read through the migration guide. The .gcloudignore file is the standard one with a few minor additions, I'll update the question with it. I can obviously not list the source files in .gcloudignore, as AppEngine needs them to build, I just don't want them to propagate to the deployed image.

Comment: As you don't want the vendor files, can you try adding a line "/vendor/" to your .gcloudignore file.

Comment: @GouravB As I mentioned in the post, that will prevent the files from being uploaded to AppEngine, which fails the compile. I also want it not to deploy the application sources, either, just the binary it produces and the supplemental HTML/CSS/etc files needed.

Comment: [Here](https://pkg.go.dev/go/build#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages) is a way to exclude source code from go packages, please see if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately adding "//go:binary-only-package" does not make any difference. The document also notes that it was supported "in Go 1.12 and earlier". The deployed AppEngine still contains the complete source code (app and vendored libraries).

Comment: This looks like more of a "go" issue than a "GAE" issue. Can you please try on your local machine and check on go build package artifacts.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. The Go build process works as expected, it's the step after the Go build (which is run remotely), when the build is uploaded to the App Engine server that I have problems with.

Comment: Please see the [Vendoring dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/specifying-dependencies#vendoring_dependencies), if it helps.

Comment: If you look at the file list in the second example, it does have vendored code. The problem is that the vendored *source* end up in the package deployed to App Engine by the online build process. In all cases, the online builder is fed all the sources it expects just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent unnecessary files from being deployed by using the `app.yaml` option [`skip_files`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/config/appref#skip_files)

> The `skip_files` element specifies which files in the application directory are not to be uploaded to App Engine. The value is either a regular expression, or a list of regular expressions. Any filename that matches any of the regular expressions is omitted from the list of files to upload when the application is uploaded. Filenames are relative to the project directory.

Comment: skip_files isn't listed in the reference doc for Go. It's listed for Python. Are you saying it applies to all languages?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `skip_files` isn't listed in the reference doc for `Go`. As per this [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/140955155) I can say it is not publicly documented. but I think we can still use that.

Comment: The documentation says one cannot combine `skip_files` and `.gcloudignore`

Comment: @nafmo Yes, you are right! You can use either of them. but, not both. Can you tell what kind of files you are trying to ignore? Can you share your `.gcloudignore` and `app.yaml`(handlers part)?

Comment: I am trying to make the version that deploys to AppEngine not include the sources, only the files needed runtime (basically the "html" subdirectory). Since the build is in the cloud, I must upload all the sources, but I don't want them available to the running instance. In the old build mode, I do get the html subdirectory and the main.go file in the deployed image, in the go.mod build mode everything is in the deployed image, increasing the image size ten-fold (and potentially exposing the sources).

Comment: @nafmo Are you looking for something similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9814677/18265570)?

Comment: @RoopaM, yeah, I haven't found anything similar for the Go run-time (ideally I want an include list, not an exclude list).

Comment: If you are still unable to do with `Go`. feel free to contact [google support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Comment: Google's support pages says to ask here... :-)